# Circular Generics Syntax

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following scenario that I can't figure out how to properly declare that allows me to use the type enforcement.  Removing the `where` clauses works fine but I'd rather be able to use them to enforce type safety.  Any ideas how I can make this work?

```
class ClassA<TB, TC> where TB : ClassB where TC : ClassC
{
    private TB MyPropB;
    private TC MyPropC;
}

class ClassB<TC> where TC : ClassC
{
    private TC MyPropC;
}

class ClassC<TB> where TB : ClassB
{
    private TB MyPropB;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to model here?  What you have won't work because you don't have types `ClassB` and `ClassC` but only types `ClassB<TC>` and `ClassC<TB>` (generic classes).

Comment: It's not recursive, it's circular

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Of course...  I've been chasing my tail so long trying to figure this out I couldn't tell circular from recursive.  ;)  I renamed the post for the benefit of others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying two generic type parameters in each class seems to work:

```
class ClassA<TB, TC>
    where TB : ClassB<TB, TC>
    where TC : ClassC<TB, TC>
{
    public TB MyPropB { get; set; }
    public TC MyPropC { get; set; }
}

class ClassB<TB, TC>
    where TB : ClassB<TB, TC>
    where TC : ClassC<TB, TC>
{
    public TC MyPropC { get; set; }
}

class ClassC<TB, TC>
    where TB : ClassB<TB, TC>
    where TC : ClassC<TB, TC>
{
    public TB MyPropB { get; set; }
}
```

`ClassB` needs `TC` for its own property and `TB` for the type parameter in the where clause for `ClassC` which has a `TB` property and vice versa. It seems to make sense to have two generic type parameters everywhere, since the classes `ClassB` and `ClassC` always work together as pairs.

---

You can define concrete classes like this:

```
class Ape : ClassA<Bear, Cougar>
{
}

class Bear : ClassB<Bear, Cougar>
{
}

class Cougar : ClassC<Bear, Cougar>
{
}
```

Comment: That feels really weird writing it that way but it seems to work perfectly.  Many thanks!!!